# PHP : how to have a extended interface for a class that inherite from another class with its own interface?

Tags: php, inheritance, interface

I have something like :

```
interface IProduct { }
class Product implements IProduct { }
class SpecificProduct extends Product { }
```

I need to have a interface, that extends IProduct, for my SpecificProduct.
Can I just do something like :

```
interface ISpecificProduct { }
class SpecificProduct extends Product implements ISpecificProduct { }
```

or will it overwrite the IProduct interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in PHP, this way, just go through:

`class SpecificProduct` as it `extends Product` it `implements IProduct` already. As it `implements ISpecificProduct` as well, it has both interfaces.

`SpecificProduct` now has two interfaces then:

1. `IProduct`
2. `ISpecificProduct`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, and no, it will not "overwrite" `IProduct`, it adds to it.

In case you are using the `ISpecificProduct` interface somewhere and would like to know about the methods in `IProduct`, `ISpecificProduct` can also extend `IProduct`:

```
interface ISpecificProduct extends IProduct
```

In this case, `SpecificProduct` gains knowledge of the method signatures from `IProduct` in two ways.

See [PHP documentation on interfaces](https://www.php.net/interface) for more information.

---

As a side note, if you have a matching interface for every concrete class, there is probably something inefficient or unnecessary going on in your object design.

Comment: What's bad if each class implements an interface?

Comment: @hakre That's not what I said is bad -- what is bad is having only one implementation of every interface, and every implementation requiring an interface.  There's just no benefit gained from such a design.

Comment: I was just asking, so thanks for your feedback. Inside tests, you often have fake objects that can heavily benefit from interfaces, even if the base code only has one class per interface (at first). So maybe that'S something to consider.

Comment: @hakre Good point, in that case I suppose you'd have two implementations, even if one is only in test and not in production.